# Search for user posts doesn't work the way I think it should

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you search by user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/how-do-you-search-by-user)

On https://superuser.com/search it states:

**posts from a specific user    user:1234 apples oranges**

However when I run a search for my own posts:

```
user:kmarsh
```

I get many threads that I have never participated in, such as the first two hits:

https://superuser.com/questions/22942/64-bits-dual-monitor-games-closed

[Why wouldn't I want to run Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64 instead of Windows 7 Ultimate x64?](https://superuser.com/questions/22945/why-wouldnt-i-want-to-run-windows-server-2008-r2-enterprise-x64-instead-of-windo)

Is this my misunderstanding of a fairly simple looking search term, a bug that only affects my username, or a general bug?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Thanks for the duplicate, but that "duplicate" just says user:*id* and not realizing that it really means numeric id only, would not have led me to the answer I found here. I would have gone on being frustrated trying to use my login name. Nonetheless it was an honor to be edited by The Jeff.

Comment: Names aren't unique. Try `user:me` or `user:4969` (your id)

Comment: Thank you, Chris. Those searches work fine. Where is this documented? Where do I even find my user ID (other than ask Chris?) It's not on the page linked to my username.

Comment: This begs another question... since no one else with a username of kmarsh is involved in those threads, just what does the search engine think it is returning?

Comment: @kmarsh: To find your user ID, look at the URL of your user page. It's the number before your name (101547 here on Meta).

Comment: I should have said as names aren't unique the search doesn't use them - sorry for causing more confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Allow searching by user name instead of user number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43594/search-by-user-name-not-working)
- [How do you search for questions filtered by a particular user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/how-do-you-search-by-user)

User names aren't unique, as ChrisF pointed out, which makes it infeasible to search by username.

To search for posts by a specific user you have to use use `user:user_id`, with an alternative shorthand `user:me`.

To see your user name you should look at the url of your profile:

`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/101547/kmarsh` (The number in bold is your user id in Meta SO.)

Comment: Nice, I never knew about `user:me` before!  Too bad I've already memorized my user ID.