# Cannot edit a post after a mod tag was added to it

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, moderator-tags

I'm having [this same problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/cant-edit-a-post-thats-been-marked-with-a-moderator-tag-without-removing-the-ta), but when I remove the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag to edit a post, it says that the "**status-completed moderator tag must be present**"

Is this intended behavior? The net result is that you can't edit a post that's been marked with a moderator tag

Comment: There was a recent change to this -- I tried rolling back a mod tag edit and failed. Hold on, let me find the question.

Comment: Here we go: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66181/revisions -- I tried to roll it back in revision 10, but it didn't work. I then rolled back to revision 1, which did remove the tag, so I guess all the kinks haven't been worked out of whatever was changed. I'm assuming that this has something to do with your problem, though it may be unrelated.

Comment: I just hit this when trying to edit this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73039/how-to-right-to-left-chat-room

Comment: Got it a couple of minutes ago trying to modify http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73300/stackapps-is-becoming-the-land-of-off-topic-closed-questions

Comment: While the error message is bad, I assume the "can't edit" part is intentional; this prevents you from changing the question after a moderator has already addressed it.

Comment: FWIW, we can still retag (at least using the in-page retagging tool): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/74028/revisions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should now be fixed. Sorry for the regression, we were removing some duplicated code, and this is one of those edge conditions.