# How to right-to-left chat room?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, chat, internationalization, rtl

We need right-to-left layout, at least for messages, in our chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/418/persian. How to achieve that?

Comment: You couldn't elaborate more? In nearly eight years nothing has changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Stack Exchange sites (including the chat rooms) do not yet support localization. There is no way to set up a site or a chat room to properly display Persian text. Localization is planned but no date has been established, yet

Comment: Is it planned? BTW showing RTL text is a matter of setting dir="rtl" on parent element (e.g. 'div' or 'p').

Comment: Localization *is* planned but no date has been established, yet. I added that to my post.

Comment: 7.5 years later, any update?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Don't know. It's been about 1-1/2 years since renewed Q&A development has been *just around the corner,* so I have to back away from this and let someone more in-the-know answer.

Comment: Thanks. But with this new SO for Teams project, isn't there any RTL support planned?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know. Maybe ask in meta?

Comment: Good idea @Robert, might do it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a hack, but this script changes Farsi looking lines to right-to-left alignment:

```
$('div.content').filter(':not(.gmRTLOldMessage)').addClass('gmRTLOldMessage')
.filter(function(){
var div = $(this);
var text = div.text();
var rtlLetter = text.replace(/[^\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\uFB50-\uFDFF\u2000-\u206F]+/g,'');
var neutral = text.replace(/[^\s\d.,()!?\-+*\/\\]+/g, '');
return rtlLetter.length  > (text.length - neutral.length) / 2;
}).css('direction','rtl');
$('.monologue .timestamp').css('margin-left','5px');
```

Needs some tweaking.

Here's a user script which runs that every second, it *seems* to be working:
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/93396

Comment: Thanks! Currently My Greasemonkey is not working on Firefox 4.0b8. I'll check it later.

Answer (score 4):

As a side note to Robert's reply... while chat is a bit more relaxed than SO, there are some obvious [babel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_babel) problems (in particular with moderation) of too many languages. Chat, however, serves also a *social* function (in addition to *technical* content), so I think we need to continue playing this "by ear" for now. I honestly don't know what the full answer is here - it isn't a simple one.

But to repeat Robert's point; we don't have current support for that right now.

Comment: What about '42'?