# Chat bug with displaying starred message in Hebrew

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, hebrew

I've noticed that there is a bug in displaying Hebrew symbols when a message is starred. Here we go:

- [The message sample](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15833964#15833964):

> [image]

- Message is starred:

> [image]

As you can see, it's displayed wrong (I guess because of Hebrew direction).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73039/how-to-right-to-left-chat-room

Comment: This is RTL discrimination! ;) בושות! בושות!

Comment: Figures. @Bart - you should then edit all my questions and fix this __"SO"__ But it states for "Dear Stack Overflow" and as an introduction statement. Such changes are _minor_. And - yes, that offends me because it's in my rule to greet the community if I'm asking something from it.

Comment: I honestly did not notice this was your posts. I'm editing several at the moment, as you can see from my recent activity history. As for the salutations http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts But have it your way.

Comment: @Bart you should notice - that while mentioned thread is useful, accepted and max-rated answer there starts with _" __I've__ always been against ..."_ . So, it's opinion of author of that post. I respect this, but why shouldn't I follow my own principle as long as it won't break any MSO/SO rule? Being polite is mandatory for me. ( _in any case, your  __grammar__ edit was useful, thank you_ )

Comment: I'm not going to drag this discussion out any further. If you feel such edits are inappropriate and need further input from the community, go for it and ask a Meta question. This is not the place. Granted, I won't stop making such edits either, but I'm not going to get into a rollback war over this.

Comment: @Lix If you're trying to say "shame", that's בושה.

Comment: @Scimonster Not in Yiddish/Yeshivish :P

Answer (score 2):

Easily fixed by adding a &lrm; before the how-long-ago indicator.