# StackApps is becoming the land of Off-topic closed questions

Tags: support, status-completed, stackapps

In the abandoned desert land of [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) there's an increasing number of Off-topic questions that clutter the homepage.<sup>*</sup>
Could you please delete them to keep a reasonable level of decorum around there?

<sup>* V1 Api was frozen 6 months ago and there's not much to talk about, except for the bug/feature-request stuff</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we need at least one or two community moderators there.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one: https://stackapps.com/questions/1841/where-can-i-find-the-androids-app-code-closed